# Couchdb compaction and deleted documents

Tags: version-control, couchdb, compact-database

When I delete document its revision is increased, then PUT the same document, its revision is increased. After compaction, PUT the same document, its revision is started from 1. And now, when I got document, I have the message, that this document was deleted.

After second time I do PUT the same document, I have document, with revision before compaction + 1, and after GET this document, shows me correctly actual state.
Why ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an instance of [COUCHDB-1415](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1415), which happens if you delete a document then attempt to insert the document again with exactly the same content. The workaround is to add changed data to the document before inserting a new revision after the delete happens.

From the bug, looks like it will be fixed in 2.0, which is being worked on at the moment.